# Esri Arcgis Maps not showing correct Pin Points WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis

I have WPF application where I am using ESRI Maps control. Here is my XAML and C# code. Problem is it shows me pin point on the map but it shows me at a wrong place i.e. somewhere Africa. I think its taking the latitiude and logitude as 0,0 i.e. center. Anyone please help me with the issue for the map to pin point to the right location.

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="10" Background="LightBlue">
                                    <!--ESRI-->
                                    <esri:Map Name="DashboardMap" Width="550" Height="300" BorderThickness="3" WrapAround="True" IsLogoVisible="False" Loaded="DashboardMap_Loaded" Margin="5,5,0,0">


                                    </esri:Map>
                                </Border>
```

Here is my CS code.

```
  private void DashboardMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                Layer Arlayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
                {
                    ID = "StreetLayer",
                    Url = "http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"
                };
                DashboardMap.Layers.Add(Arlayer);

    }

                GraphicsLayer layer;

            MapPoint point = new MapPoint(37.428433999999996, -122.0723816);
                    point.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(102100);
                    //point.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
                    //point.SpatialReference = DashboardMap.SpatialReference;
                    layer = new GraphicsLayer();
                    layer.Visible = true;

                    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
                    symbol.Color = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    symbol.Style = ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol.SimpleMarkerStyle.Circle;
                    symbol.Size = 15;
                    Graphic graphic = new Graphic();
                    graphic.Symbol = symbol;
                    graphic.Geometry = point;
                    graphic.SetZIndex(1);
                    layer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
                    DashboardMap.Layers.Add(layer);
                }
}
```

Comment: How about EPSG:4326? I guess coordinates in EPSG:102100 are measured in meters, not degrees.

Comment: Yea when I use 4326 it marks Denmark. But still the latitude and longitude belongs to USA California.

Comment: MapPoint constructor takes parameters x and y, hence first longitude then latitude.

Comment: Thanks Clemens it worked. U are awersome. I have been struggling on this for 5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapPoint takes parameters x and y in that order, so first longitude, then latitude.

You should write:

```
var point = new MapPoint(-122.072382, 37.428434, new SpatialReference(4326));
```